# MySql C API: are prepared statement named parameters supported?

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

I port native C++ application from SQLite to MySql. In SQLite it is possible to use named prepared statement parameters like following one:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `Id` = @Id
```

In MySql documentation says nothing about such feature. Instead, in MySql we use unnamed parameters like following one:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `Id` = ?
```

It is not a problem when query is very easy; however, for complex query with 10-15 parameters this way looks bad if you have to update statment; you have to control yourself that each unnamed parameter is in correct position and remember what index in parameters array is for what question sign. So, for me it looks unusual that in MySql there are no support for named prepared statements parameters.

Are there any way in MySql C API to use named parameters on prepared statements instead of unnamed ones represented with question signs?

Answer (score 0):

There are not "official" support to this feature like we have it in SQLite. However, it is possible to emulate it.
Instead of sending 1 command:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `Id` = ?
```

It is required to send 2 ones:

```
SET @Id = 1
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `Id` = @Id
SET @Id = NULL
```

When you have query parameters as name-value pairs (for example, `std:unordered_map`), it is not a problem to generate SQL queries that create and clean variables automatically. Of course, instead of 1 query you have to send as many queries as many variables you have, and also the same amount of queries to clean variables if you need it. You also at risk to override any variable if you use variables in your SQL queries. However, this approach is still usable and much more comfortable in complex queries than unnamed parameters.